# Proof that the time of the k-th return is a stopping time

Tags: probability, markov-chains, stopping-times

I am having trouble with proving that a radnom varible defined as the time of the $k$-th return is a stopping time. My motivation for proving this comes from a textbook/notes that im currently reading: [https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf). In the book it is taken as fact that the time of the $k$-th return is a stopping time but I don't seem to find it that easy to prove. I have tried proof with induction, but I can't seem to finish it. The definitions I am working with come from the book (they can be accessed from the link I have pasted), but I will also paste them here:

For a Markov chain $X_{0}, X_{1}, ...$ a random variable $T$ with values in $\{\mathbb{N}_0 \cup {\infty}\}$ is called a stopping time if for any $n$ the event ${T = n}$ depends only on the random variables ${X_0, X_1, ..., X_n}$.

The random variable $T^k_s = min(n > T^{k-1}_s, X_n = s)$, where $s \in S$ is the initial state ($X_0 = s$), is called the time of the $k$-th return, that is, the time when the Markov chain returns to state $s$ for the $k$-th time.

My attempt:

If $k = 1$ then the time of the first return can be written as $T_s = min\{ n > 1, X_n = s\}$ which is by definition a stopping time, since it has its values in $\{ \mathbb{N}_0 \cup \infty \}$ and it's value is solely based on the state $X_n$.

Now assume this holds for $k$. We want to show that $T_s^{k+1}$ is a stopping time. Since $T_s^k$ is a stopping time, I would argue that by the srong Markov property this holds for $k + 1$, since after the state $X_{T_s^{k}} = s$ is reached, we are left with the same markov chain and are starting in the same state $s$, so assuming that $T_s^{k} < \infty$,  $T_s^{k+ 1}$ can be written as $T_s^k + T_s$

Is my reasoning correct?

Note: There is a question like this, that already exist's but I dont quite uderstand the answer.

Comment: Hint: prove the first return time is a stopping time, then argue by induction.

Comment: Thanks, will try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that the $k$th return to $y$ is a stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191180/how-to-show-that-the-kth-return-to-y-is-a-stopping-time)

Comment: I don't understand why that proved that $T_s^{k+1}$ is a stopping time, according to the definition.